# MS Outlook 2010 - Shared "Unread Mail" for multiple email accounts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have multiple Email accounts and account files for the (*.pst) respectively in Outlook 2010.

Now what I want to do is to make **ONE SHARED "unread mail" folder** for all those accounts (can be created separably for each account under "search folders") is that possible ?

I'm using MS Office x86 pack on Win7 x64 version if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to create a new folder, called for instance "Unified Inbox", have a rule defined such that any incoming mail gets moved to that folder. There are [couple](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/set-up-single-inbox-folder-for-all-accounts-in-outlook-2010/) of blog posts [that should](http://lifehacker.com/5515379/use-outlook-rules-to-create-a-single-unified-inbox) give you step by by step instructions, if the above aren't clear enough.

Comment: THNX  I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

Add a predefined Search Folder

1. In Mail, on the Folder tab, in the New group, click New Search Folder.

Keyboard shortcut    To create a Search Folder, click CTRL+SHIFT+P.

2. From the Select a Search Folder list, click the Search Folder you want to add.
3. If prompted, under Customize Search Folder, specify the search criteria to use.
4. To select a different mailbox to search, under Customize Search Folder, click the arrow at the Search mail in box, and then select the mailbox from the list.

   Tip    To change the criteria for a Search Folder, right-click the folder in the Navigation Pane, click Customize this Search Folder, click Criteria, and then change the criteria. The criteria of Search Folders in the Reading Mail group, such as Inbox, Drafts or Sent Items, can’t be changed.